# Installing windows 8 on a second hard drive on a Mac

Tags: multi-boot, macbook-pro, boot-camp, windows-8-preview

I just downloaded the windows 8 developer preview and set my secodary internal hard drive to gpt partition scheme windows installer runs fine until I get to the end of the file extraction then get an error saying that work does could not update the boot configuration file has anyone had any luck triple booting win8 win7 and Mac osx using this configuration ? Want to keep windows 8 off my my main drive if possible In case something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

you could always try unplugging the other drive while you install Windows 8, then sort the boot loader afterwards once its installed using something like Easy BCD
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml